# Crafting a CSS selector to find unique values for multiple elements with the same name

Tags: html, selenium, collections, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have 6 buttons on a page layout, all called "Add content" and all of class "addContent".
I have to click on each inturn, using Webdriver and then perform seperate tasks. The only unique attributes each button has so far as I can see is that they live within div's that have unique ID numbers.  However, the button's are buried deep. Example of button one:-

```
   <div id="1405365670286" class="row_item empty_row span_3col ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <div class="controls span_3col" style="display: none;">
      <ul>
        <li>
           <a class="edit" href="" title="Edit" style="display: none;">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a class="remove" href="" title="Remove">Remove</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="" class="tile nocontent">
     <a id="AddContents" class="addContent actionButton button" href="">Add content</a>
  </div>
```

1. Can someone provide me with a cssselector to access this button?
2. Is there a cleaner way of giving Webdriver access to each button and knowing which is being referred to?  Maybe by creating a List of WebElements and giving each an index?

Comment: You could use XPath to base your search on "what's around the element". By this I mean get an element where it's next to another element. So, for instance, is the "Add contents" button always near the "Edit" and "Remove" button? Do they change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findElements()`:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#AddContents"));
```

You can then use the list, and access the buttons by index.

Comment: I have tried this but when I do: System.out.println(buttons.size());  It always comes back as 0 ?

Comment: In the question it's mentioned that all buttons have class "addContent". So just use `By.className("addContent")` here.

Comment: Ok, it was a synchronisation issue.

Comment: @Steerpike 9 out of 10 Selenium problems are synchronization issues :-)